# onActivityResult not called when app restored from Overview Screen (recents)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, onactivityresult

I have 2 Activities, Parent and Child. Parent acts as a Widget configuration class as it handles an intent filter for APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE.

Selecting an item on Parent starts Child for editing.

```
Intent addNewIntent = new Intent(this,Child.class);
this.startActivityForResult(addNewIntent, EDIT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
```

Child returns the result

```
...
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
     finish();
```

onActivityResult in the Parent class is called and the result is processed

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
switch (requestCode){
         //EditShortcutActivity returned
         case EDIT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST:
             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
...
```

When an AppWidget is added to the home screen, the Parent activity is started from the APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE intent. The Child activity can be started and Parent.onActivity result is invoked. Works fine.

Once an item is selected from Parent, *finish()* is called and the widget is configured properly. The Parent activity is closed and the home screen is shown.

Now if the user selects the Parent activity again from the Overview Screen (recent apps selector), then the user selects an item to edit, a Child activity is again opened. When changes are saved, *onActivityResult()* is not called in the Parent activity this time.

Also, *getCallingActivity()* returns null in the Child activity in only this case.

I assume this has something to do with the Task that Parent is started in because it was started from the AppWidget configuration.

How I can get the *onActivityResult()* called reliably?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have never figured out exactly why this happens, however I found a workaround. When the Activity is called to configure the Widget, I manually remove it from the history stack by appending flags to the Intent.

```
Intent currentIntent = getIntent();
currentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
setIntent(noBackstack);
```

When the Activity is started normally from the launcher, it is shown in the history (overview) and works as expected. When started by to configure the AppWidget it is no longer shown in the history.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I could never get `onActivityResult` called reliably. I came up with a work-around instead.

Remove the Activity from the history stack when it is started for configuring a widget. See the EDIT for the code.